# Streaming mp4 requests via http with range header in grails

Tags: http, grails, safari, video-streaming, mp4

I'm on an old grails 2.5.1 app and I noticed mp4 video files served from the server don't play in Safari. I looked up the issue on SO and got some hints that it has to do with the range header. But I suspect the way I'm handling the range header isn't quite right.

So far, what I've found is Mac OS Safari 11.0 (11604.1.38.1.7) (I don't care about ios Safari right now) sends two GET requests. Firstly, it sends one with:

```
host:     localhost:8080
accept:     text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
user-agent:     Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Safari/604.1.38
accept-language:     en-us
accept-encoding:     gzip, deflate
x-request-time:     t=****
x-forwarded-for:     *.*.*.*
x-forwarded-host:     *.com
x-forwarded-server:     *.com
connection:     Keep-Alive
cookie: ...TOO BIG TO SHOW HERE
<- "GET /.../videos/lol.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 200 186ms
```

Subsequently, it sends second GET request:

```
host:     localhost:8080
language:     en-us
playback-session-id:     03F1B4E6-F97E-****
bytes=0-1
accept:     */*
user-agent:     Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Safari/604.1.38
https://.../videos/lol.mp4
encoding:     identity
request-time:     t=****
forwarded-for:     *.*.*.*
forwarded-host:     *.com
forwarded-server:     *.com
connection:     Keep-Alive
cookie: ...TOO BIG TO SHOW HERE
<- "GET /uiv2/videos/lol.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 206 149ms
```

Debugging this is hard because Safari web inspector doesn't show you much. In fact, it doesn't even show you all the headers it sends so I had to get this from the back end.

As can be seen, the difference between request 1 and 2 is the 2nd has playback-session-id and range.

The hard part is finding out how to please Safari in how range and playback-session-id are handled.

I've made a controller to return the range of bytes requested, if they're requested. But still no luck.

```
import grails.compiler.GrailsTypeChecked
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured
import asset.pipeline.grails.AssetResourceLocator
import grails.util.BuildSettings
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplication
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource

class VideoController {
    GrailsApplication grailsApplication
    AssetResourceLocator assetResourceLocator

    public index() {
        Resource mp4Resource = assetResourceLocator.findAssetForURI('/../lol.mp4');

        response.addHeader("Content-type", "video/mp4")
        response.addHeader( 'Accept-Ranges', 'bytes')

        String range = request.getHeader('range')
        if(range) {
            String[] rangeKeyValue = range.split('=')
            String[] rangeEnds = rangeKeyValue[1].split('-')
            if(rangeEnds.length  > 1) {
                int startByte = Integer.parseInt(rangeEnds[0])
                int endByte = Integer.parseInt(rangeEnds[1])
                int contentLength = (endByte - startByte) + 1
                byte[] inputBytes = new byte[contentLength]
                mp4Resource.inputStream.read(inputBytes, startByte, contentLength)
                response.status = 206
                response.addHeader( 'Content-Length', "${contentLength}")
                response.outputStream << inputBytes

            } else {
                response.addHeader( 'Content-Length', "${mp4Resource.contentLength()}")
                response.outputStream << mp4Resource.inputStream
            }
        } else {
            log.info 'no range, so responding with whole mp4'
            response.addHeader( 'Content-Length', "${mp4Resource.contentLength()}")
            response.outputStream << mp4Resource.inputStream
        }
    }
}
```

In the Safari console, I get:

```
Failed to load resource: Plug-in handled load
```

Nothing else. And sadly lots of fields in the web inspector are blank even though they're obviously set in the server.

[image]

I've tried so many things at this point that any help, pointers, tips will be appreciated. Thanks guys :) !

Answer (score 1):

After trying many things and scouring many posts, this formula worked. You need all four of those headers. Don't need to return anything in the first request. This may not work for all browsers but this works for safari. Additional modifications can ensure all browsers are handled

```
class VideoController {
    GrailsApplication grailsApplication
    AssetResourceLocator assetResourceLocator

    public index() {
        Resource mp4Resource = assetResourceLocator.findAssetForURI('/../lol.mp4')

        String range = request.getHeader('range')
        if(range) {
            String[] rangeKeyValue = range.split('=')
            String[] rangeEnds = rangeKeyValue[1].split('-')
            if(rangeEnds.length  > 1) {
                int startByte = Integer.parseInt(rangeEnds[0])
                int endByte = Integer.parseInt(rangeEnds[1])
                int contentLength = (endByte - startByte) + 1
                byte[] inputBytes = new byte[contentLength]
                def inputStream = mp4Resource.inputStream
                inputStream.skip(startByte) // input stream always starts at the first byte, so skip bytes until you get to the start of the requested range
                inputStream.read(inputBytes, 0, contentLength) // read from the first non-skipped byte
                response.reset() // Clears any data that exists in the buffer as well as the status code and headers
                response.status = 206
                response.addHeader("Content-Type", "video/mp4")
                response.addHeader( 'Accept-Ranges', 'bytes')
                response.addHeader('Content-Range', "bytes ${startByte}-${endByte}/${mp4Resource.contentLength()}")
                response.addHeader( 'Content-Length', "${contentLength}")
                response.outputStream << inputBytes
            }
        }
    }
}
```